# Retornar un array con los valores booleanos en una funcion

Tags: javascript, funciones, booleano

Estoy intentando resolver el siguiente ejercicio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando resolverlo pero no entiendo muy bien como resolverlo ¿Alguna ayuda?

```
   function getKeysOfBooleanValues(obj) {
    // tu código aquí

  const entries = Object.entries(obj)

entries.forEach(entry => {
  const property = entry[0]
  const value = entry[1]
  
  console.log(`${property}: ${value}`)
  
  if (typeof value ==="boolean" ){
   return  property

}

})

  }
  
console.log(getKeysOfBooleanValues({ a: true, b: 42, c: false }))
```

Comment: La descripción del problema debiera estar en texto. Recordar que uno de los objetivos es que esta pregunta sea indexada por buscadores, para que pueda servir a otros con un problema similar en el futuro.

Comment: En este caso, puedes utilizar la función filter para filtrar las claves que son de tipo booleano y la función map para crear un array con los nombres de las claves. Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo se vería el código For more info read this blog [download undawn apk mod](https://modlonely.com/undawn-apk/)

Answer (score 3):

Más sencillo sería utilizar la función `Object.keys()` para devolver un array con todas las propiedades del objeto `obj`. Una vez teniendo las propiedades, filtramos solo las propiedades en el que sus valores sean tipo de dato `boolean`, devolviendo un nuevo array, por ejemplo:

```js
function getKeysOfBooleanValues(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).filter(key => typeof obj[key] === 'boolean');
}

console.log(getKeysOfBooleanValues({ a: true, b: 42, c: false }))
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma es usando [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), que devuelve un array de arrays con los pares clave/valor del objeto, y aplicar una función  [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) a dicho arreglo:

```js
const object = {
  name: 'nicholas',
  registered: true,
  age: 27,
  married: false,
}

function getKeysOfBooleanValues(object) {
  return Object.entries(object).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if(typeof curr[1] === 'boolean') acc.push(curr[0])
    return acc
  } ,[])
}
console.log(getKeysOfBooleanValues(object))
```

O el que para mi se entiende mejor, usando un for-in y la notacion de [brackets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) para los objetos:

```js
const object = {
  name: 'nicholas',
  registered: true,
  age: 27,
  married: false,
}

function getKeysOfBooleanValues2(object) {
  let result = []
  for(const prop in object) {
    if(typeof object[prop] === 'boolean') result.push(prop)
  }
  return result
}
console.log(getKeysOfBooleanValues2(object))
```

En ambos casos utilizo [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) para determinar el tipo del dato, pregunta cualquier duda.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno en este caso puedes usar filter para filtrar las llaves que son de tipo boolean y map para crear un arreglo con los nombres de las llaves.
Este es un ejemplo de como seria

```
function getKeysOfBooleanValues(obj) {
    return Object.entries(obj)
        .filter(ent => {
            return typeof ent[1] === "boolean"
        })
        .map(ent => ent[0])
}
```